# how to add beat and bass effect in video using ffmpeg command?

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, android, video-editing, ios

i want beat effect on video and i am using ffmpeg command for beat effect 
i was used this below command for beat effect black and white and original color after 2 sec looping but not this work this command only create black and white video 
ffmpeg -i addition.mp4 -vf hue=s=0 output.mp4

So please, suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a link to an example so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: thx for your response, i want make video like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fG7TVKGcqI plaese suggest me